# Just how 'approximate' is ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount()?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The javadocs for [ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount()) say that the method "Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks."

What makes this number approximate, and not exact? Will it over or under-report active threads?

Here is the method:

```
/**
 * Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively
 * executing tasks.
 *
 * @return the number of threads
 */
public int getActiveCount() {
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        int n = 0;
        for (Worker w : workers)
            if (w.isLocked())
                ++n;
        return n;
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method takes the worker list and counts the workers that are being locked.

By the time counting reaches the end of the list, some of the workers previously counted may have finished. (Or some unused workers may have been given a task.)

But you shouldn't be relying on this knowledge as a client, just the fact that it's a best effort approximation. Note that this "inaccuracy" isn't a result of sloppy implementation, it's inherent in every truly multi-threaded system. In such systems there's no global moment of "present". Even if you stop all the workers to count them, by the time you return the result, it may be inaccurate.

Comment: So this would mean that the number you get could be greater than the actual number of active threads (if some have finished by the time you're done counting)

Comment: @eric It could be both greater or smaller. There's no way to tell. In fact, in a multi-threaded system the question itself doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks, will accept this answer in four minutes when SO lets me :-)

Comment: A different way of saying it:  The best that the method could possibly do is to return a result that was correct at some moment in time, but before the caller can make a decision based on the result, the moment will have passed.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, though in this case there may not even have been a moment in time when the result was correct, as workers aren't stopped while the iteration is going. In a particularly unlucky scenario, you may even get a count of 0, even though in every moment there were exactly `poolsize-1` threads at work all the time.

Comment: When I wrote, "best that the method could possibly do", I was thinking of your, "stop all the workers to count them."  Theoretically possible, but not smart.  I was trying to draw attention to how, when we try to prove the correctness of a multi-threaded program, we may have to accept a weaker "correctness" than we're accustomed to with single-threaded programs.  E.g., Can't prove the order that items will appear in a lock-free queue when there is no "happens-before" relationship between the producers that feed it.  Or, as you said, "There is no global moment of present."